# How to run SUDO command in WinSCP to transfer files from Windows to linux

Tags: linux, sudo, winscp

I am trying to use WinSCP to transfer files over to a Linux Instance from Windows.

I'm using private key for my instance to login to Amazon instance using `ec2-user`. However `ec2-user` does not have access to write to the Linux instance

How do I `sudo su` - to access the root directory and write to the Linux box, using WinSCP or any other file transfer method?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**AFAIK you can't do that.**
 What I did at my place of work, is transfer the files to your `home` (`~`) folder (or really any folder that you have full permissions in, i.e `chmod 777` or variants) via WinSCP, and then SSH to to your linux machine and `sudo` from there to your destination folder.

Another solution would be to change permissions of the directories you are planning on uploading the files to, so your user (which is without `sudo` privileges) could write to those dirs.

I would also read about [WinSCP Remote Commands](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command) for further detail.

Comment: It not really true that this is not possible. References: Duplicate question: [WinSCP connect to Amazon AMI EC2 Instance changing user after login to “root”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6414158/850848), WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su), WinSCP support forum thread: [Using WinSCP to upload to an ec2 server](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9476), Article [Connect to Amazon’s Linux via WinSCP as root](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/10/connect-to-amazons-linux-via-winscp-as-root/).

Comment: Incorrect. There are actually a few different ways to accomplish this.

Comment: incorrect answer, please see the top answer above. don't know how an incorrect answer will be accepted?

Comment: Please edit this question to real answer and if you want to keep the useful data of your answer, keep it. But this is very mistaken.

Answer (score 143):

I know this is old, but it is actually **very possible**.

- Go to your WinSCP profile (Session > Sites > Site Manager)
- Click on Edit > Advanced... > Environment > SFTP
- Insert `sudo su -c /usr/lib/sftp-server` in "SFTP Server" *(note this path might be different in your system)*
- Save and connect

[Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74011/how-can-i-connect-to-the-sftp-server-with-sudo-via-winscp)

AWS Ubuntu 18.04:
[image]

Comment: For more details see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

Comment: its ```/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server``` for Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: @Mr.Shan0 I love you :D FYI I think this is for Amazon Linux 2 which is CentOS-based... Amazon Linux is Ubuntu-based and uses /usr/lib/sftp-server

Comment: /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server     for ubuntu 14

Comment: Just to add to this- I'm using openssh on CentOS 7, "sudo su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server" worked for me, but only *after* editing the sudoers file to comment out "Defaults !visiblepw".

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18 (`sudo su -c /usr/lib/sftp-server`)

Comment: Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?
on the server, the SFTP server is running.

Comment: Same as @Biodiversity I am getting an "Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?" error on WinSCP. I've verified my sftp-server path is correct too.

Comment: For centos`sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`

Comment: Here is a working command for Amazon Lightstail server (Ubuntu): `sudo su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

Comment: For Debian12: SFTP setting `sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` (found by `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep -i sftp-server`) and I had to add `myusername ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` in any file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`

Answer (score 69):

There is an option in WinSCP that does exactly what you are looking for:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Error: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended).

Comment: I solve this problem with change root instead of user and change  root password.

Comment: I used sudo su - <user-name> and it worked for me.

Comment: Just make sure that your `File Protocol` is `SCP` not `SFTP`

Comment: Like Rami says. That´s  it

Comment: Shell ```sudo su -``` works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Usually all users will have write access to /tmp.
Place the file to /tmp and then login to putty , then you can sudo and copy the file.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to mention for SUSE Enterprise server V15.2 on an EC2 Instance the command to add to winSCP SFTP server commands is :

`sudo su -c /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server`

I didn't have enough Reputation points to add a comment to the original answer but I had to fish this out so I wanted to add it.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` to `FreePBX` and run the commands stated below in your terminal:

```
sudo nano -f /etc/sudoers.d/my_config_file

YourUserName ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Winscp:

```
under session login ==> Advanced ==> SFTP
```

Change SFTP Server to:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: The above line is very permissive, it allows user YourUserName connected from anywhere (the first ALL) to run any command (the second ALL) as a root without being asked for password.

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same issue, and I am not sure whether it is possible or not,

tried the above solutions are not worked for me.

for a workaround, I am going with moving the files to my HOME directory, editing and replacing the files with SSH.

Comment: Yes, but in /tmp, there could be lots of application session files, I suggest to have the files in the HOME directory only to avoid the confusion and user can track their files if required they can verify.  

Can you kindly provide the solution on my question, if you have any?

Comment: If you have a question, then post a question instead of an "answer".

Comment: It's kinda workaround for the above question, as I said I am looking for the direct solution for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging this answer which helped me, might not answer the actual question

If you are using password instead of private key, please refer to this answer for tested working solution on Ubuntu 16.04.5 and 20.04.1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466397/2457076