# ssh and sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed, auth could not identify password for [username]

Tags: ssh, sudo, rsync, pam

I'm facing a weird behavior trying to run rsync as sudo through ssh with passwordless login.
This is something I do with dozens of servers, I'm having this frustrating problem connecting to a couple of Ubuntu 18.04.4 servers

**PREMISE**

1. the passwordless SSH from CLIENT to SERVER with account USER works
   nicely
2. When I'm logged in SERVER I can sudo everything with
   account USER
3. On SERVER I've added the following to */etc/sudoers*

   user  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync

Now, if I launch this simple test from machine CLIENT as user USER, I receive the following sudo error message:

```
$ ssh utente@192.168.200.135 -p 2310 sudo rsync
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Moreover, looking in the SERVER's */var/log/auth.log* I found this errors:

```
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [user]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution thanks to Centos. Infact, because of the more complex configuration of */etc/sudoers* in Centos (compared to Ubuntu or Debian), I've been forced to put my additional configurations to an external file in */etc/sudoers.d*/ instead than putting it directly into */etc/sudoers*

SOLUTION:

1. Putting additional configurations *directly into /etc/sudoers* **wouldn't work**
2. Putting the needed additional settings in a file within the directory `/etc/sudoers.d`/ **will work**

e.g. , these are the config lines put in a file named */etc/sudoers.d/my_config_file*:

```
Host_Alias MYSERVERHOST=192.168.1.135,localhost

# User that will execute Rsync with Sudo from a remote client
rsyncuser MYSERVERHOST=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

Why `/etc/sudoers` didn't work? It's unknown to me even after two days worth of Internet search. I find this very obscure and awful.

What follows is a quote from this useful article: https://askubuntu.com/a/931207

Unlike `/etc/sudoers`, the contents of /etc/sudoers.d survive system upgrades, so it's preferrable to create a file there than to modify /etc/sudoers.

For the editing of any configuration file to be used by `sudo` the command `visudo` is preferable.

i.e.

```
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/my_config_file
```

Answer (score 5):

am not an PAM expert, but tested the following solution working on Ubuntu 16.04.5 and 20.04.1

> **NOTE :** Configuration set to default on /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/my_config_file
```

add the below lines

```
my_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

and don't forget to restart sshd

```
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a custom linux server, but the solution was similar to the answers above.
As soon as I removed the line `your_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` from `/etc/sudoers`, the errors were gone.